# Formatting and Parsing Dates with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am currently trying to use `MomentJS` to format a DateTime string created from a `Bootstrap` [datatime picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) into a format my server will accept, but I am not having much luck.

**Server Requires:**

```
2014-08-26T18:40:11.627
```

**DataPicker String**

```
09/01/2014 8:15 PM
```

I dont not have access to the server to change what it will accept or to parse it on the backend. The seconds and milliseconds can always be zeros when submitting to the server, but as you can see they are not set by the datapicker.

Has anyone been able to setup a datapicker that will submit back to the server in this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom parser using the tokens specified in the [Moment Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). This works for this string, but your rules might be different.

```
function createMoment(str){
    return moment(str, "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A"); // Custom parser string using tokens
}

var obj = createMoment("09/01/2014 8:15 PM");
```